# Drag and Drop in android using RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am new to android development and i want to create an app for drag and drop functionality.The condition is when i drag an item until we drop that item at any position the position of that dragged view must be empty.

Comment: If you want to drag view in recycler view than refr this link https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Comment: You have to explain more and the sample that you have already tried.

Comment: show us some efforts @Rishikesh Rahi

Comment: @shohan-ahmed-sijan ,actually i dragged the view from one position to another but the the thing is..i want the dragged item go to its previous position when i did not drop it at some position.

Comment: @Mohit Suthar thanks for your help.It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved same problem by ItemTouchHelper. Its little but tricky but simple after understand. Suppose you have a recycleView called mRecyclerView.

```
public void initRecycleView(){
  //initiate your recycleView here ....
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(your_recycleView_adapter));
  ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(rvCallback);
  touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
}

int dragStartFromPosition = -1;
ItemTouchHelper.Callback rvCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    int dragFromPosition = -1;
    int dragToPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        //final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

        if (dragFromPosition == -1) { //For Saving drag start from position
            dragStartFromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        }

        dragFromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        dragToPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
        moveItem(dragFromPosition, dragToPosition);
        dragFromPosition = dragToPosition;
        dragToPosition = -1;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        if (dragFromPosition != -1 && dragToPosition != -1 && dragFromPosition != dragToPosition) {
            finalMoved(dragFromPosition, dragToPosition);
        } else {
            moveItem(dragFromPosition, dragStartFromPosition);
            dragStartFromPosition = -1;
        }
        dragFromPosition = dragToPosition = -1;
    }

    private void finalMoved(int from, int to) {
            moveAlertDialog(from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDrawOver(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

};

private void moveItem(int from, int to) {
    Collections.swap(itemArrayList, from, to);
    rvAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to);
}

public void moveAlertDialog(final int from, final int to) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to move this item?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("move", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dragStartFromPosition = -1;
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            moveItem(from, dragStartFromPosition);
            dragStartFromPosition = -1;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Feel free to ask question if you face any problem.
Thanks